# Virtualenv need for env

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

What is the difference between the following two commands in `virtualenv`:

```
$ virtualenv .
```

and

```
$ virtualenv envname
```

I have seen both of them used but couldn't find a clear explanation of the difference. I tend to use the first when creating projects

Comment: The argument is the path where to create the venv. `.` usually refers to the current working directory.

Comment: Hint for reviewers: Caution on trying out first command. It will potentially write to your current directory some things you don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is just a name that means "the current directory". With `.`, it means "put the virtual environment in the current directory", so correct usage would be:

```bash
$ mkdir envname
$ cd envname
$ virtualenv .
```

With a name, it says "make a new directory of this name (if needed), then put the virtual environment in it", so the same operation, from the same initial working directory, simplifies to:

```bash
$ virtualenv envname
```